# Log4j loads defined configuration, later stops and uses spring boot's log4j.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, springfox

I recently migrated a legacy spring boot project from Spring boot version 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.7.7

After the migration, I see everything working fine except the log4j initialization. I am using the latest log4j version (2.20.0) in the project.

During the application startup, I see that my log4j configuration is loaded, later stopped and it uses the spring boot jar's log4j2.xml

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI /home/vboxuser/Desktop/cande2/cande2-config/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7ff2a664) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7ff2a664] started OK.
DEBUG StatusLogger uri does not represent a local file: jar:file:/home/vboxuser/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.7/spring-boot-2.7.7.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@57175e74
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Closing JarURLInputStream sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@16afbd92
DEBUG StatusLogger Loaded configuration from jar:file:/home/vboxuser/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.7/spring-boot-2.7.7.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml
```

and that stops me from using my own log4j configuration. It also throws below error in the logs after log4j intialization.

```
2023-03-16 19:57:21.802  INFO 11942 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1243 ms
ERROR StatusLogger Recursive call to appender Console
ERROR StatusLogger Recursive call to appender Console
ERROR StatusLogger Recursive call to appender Console
```

Let me know your thoughts about this issue.

I checked and confirmed that there are no transitive log4j dependencies coming in.

Comment: What is our problem? Spring boot? Log4J? Both? Your expectations? You not following migration documentation between changes?

So not really a "java" or even a "spring-boot" problem bit more of a "log4j" issue?

Comment: Hello @BillMair, I followed the Spring migration document for the migration. After going through the spring documentation, I understood that using the VM argument `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/log4j2.xml` will not work in my case. I should instead use `-Dlogging.config=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/log4j2.xml` to let Spring logging know the location of my log4j configuration.

Comment: (`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/log4j2.xml` ) I wonder how this was working fine before the migration.

Comment: This error `ERROR StatusLogger Recursive call to appender Console` that is thrown by log4j is completely irrelevant. I see that there is already an open [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2738) with log4j about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, After going through spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging). I understood that if we do not place the log4j or logback configuration file on the classpath, We can let springboot know the location of the configuration file either by placing `logging.config` property in application.properties/application.yml or by using the JVM argument `-Dlogging.config=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/log4j2.xml`. This is only applicable to Springboot applications.

For applications that do not use Springboot (Ex: Spark Java Application), We can still use VM arguments `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/log4j2.xml` (for log4j/log4j2) and `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/<YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDERPATH>/logback.xml` (for logback)